# modify an existing collation postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, collation, postgresql-9.3

I would like to define a new collation for my bd in postgresql. I read this article ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createcollation.html ) and I decide to modify an existing collation with CREATE COLLATION mycollation FROM IT.UTF-8 but i can't add my preferences. Can someone explain me how to do it??
thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean be "preferences"? Can you show the SQL that you used for the `CREATE COLLATION`?

Comment: Why do you want to create a new collation for this? This is perfectly fine with UTF-8 (the default IMO). Create your database with UTF-8 and your good to go.

Comment: my prefences are for example: b  B, c  C,d  D,e  E,é  É so i just want to add this cases to a new collation. I'm not very expert of postgresql so i don't know how and where to start, for this reason i post this question. My teacher told me that is possible to define a new collation from an external file but i'm not able to do it. is it possible??

Comment: Maybe I found the solution. I write the command: sudo nano /usr/share/i18n/locales/ru_RU now i have only to understand where i have to write my cases